# R tcltk: change the icon of a tkmessage

Tags: r

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the picture icon of a tkmessage? I know there is a way to change the icon of the overall panel using tcl, but what about the message box? For example, can I change the 'Tk' icon to something else?

[image]

Thanks!
DD

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any options for changing the icon within a message box.  The message box function is a pretty simple, few option tool for a quick message.  If you want more functionality than it provides (i.e. the option to change that icon) then you can create your own dialog box with a label and button to do the job and change the icon the way with a regular window.

Comment: You are right Greg, that is probably the only way. I will keep this post active for several days in case others have a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

kico = 'myicon.ico' # where we have an icon we prefer to use instead of tkinter icon which icon files

## i downloaded bitmap icons (probably ibm)

## ...in the place where establishing a root window  i might have this

from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_iconbitmap(kico) # this seems to overlay in the main application and all child window tkinter dialogs etc

## ... overlays the tkinter icon in for example tkMessageBox.askokcancel dialog